# profile with sqldatareader in asp .net applications

Tags: asp.net

Hello I'm working on a library project and using the document that is helping me I got a query that refused to work for me and I need your hep please
This is my codes

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblEMsg.Visible = false;
            string[] Book;
            string Author_ID, Publisher_ID, Category_ID, Supplier_ID;
            try
            {
                string sql;
                SqlDataReader sdr;
                Profile pro = new Profile();

                //Retrieve Author ID.
                sql = "SELECT Author_ID FROM Author WHERE Author_Name = '" + LstAuthor.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
                sdr = pro.ReturnMDetails(sql);
                if (sdr.Read() == true)
                {
                    Author_ID = sdr["Author_ID"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    Author_ID = "";
                }
                sdr.Close();

                //Retrieve Publisher ID.
                sql = "SELECT Publisher_ID FROM Publisher WHERE Publisher_Name = '" + LstPublisher.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
                sdr = pro.ReturnMDetails(sql);
                if (sdr.Read() == true)
```

**The Error message is**
Error   59  The type or namespace name 'Profile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
AddBook.aspx.cs 48  17  LibraryMISProject

I have tried importing System.web.Profile but doesn't come

Comment: What is Profile here...??

Comment: It's a namespace that I'm using but I'm trying to add it in my references but it doesn't come. Can you help me with a link to which I can use?

Comment: You can't create an object of a namespace

Comment: How can I do it? Please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.Profile is a Namespace, not a class you can create an object of.

Comment: How can I add this namespace?